# 'Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host' through SVN protocol

Tags: svn

I want to checkout a work copy from a SVN server with the cmd 'svn co svn:///myPro', but encountered the error 'Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host'.
I can do the same thing at the server and can remotely access the server through ssh.

Answer (score 2):

The path is relative to the server, so there's context when you execute that command via SSH. If you run it on your local machine, `myPro` has no context. It's like trying to connect to `localhost` from two different machines -- each will take you to a different location. Try using the full path.

Comment: Thank you. You make my day!